# Emailing preceded by text files consolidation into excel

Tags: vbscript

I have two text files with following content:

**file1.txt:**

```
Windows                  1.36
Linux                    2.78
MacOS                    3.45
Ubuntu                   4.12
FreePhysicalMemory      30.12
TotalVisibleMemorySize  48.00
```

**file2.txt:**

```
MacOS                    6.39
Windows                  4.42
Linux                    5.76
Android                  3.46
FreePhysicalMemory      31.65
TotalVisibleMemorySize  48.00
```

**output.xls:**

```
OPERATING SYSTEM       SERVER1    SERVER2
Windows                  1.36     4.42
Linux                    2.78     5.76
MacOS                    3.45     6.39
Ubuntu                   4.12     0.00
Android                  0.00     3.46
FreePhysicalMemory      30.12     31.65
TotalVisibleMemorySize  48.00     48.00
```

I want to achieve following two things in a VBScript program or in any, which is appropriate to run on windows server:

1. Insert the contents of both file1.txt and fil2.txt in a excel
   sheet output.xls like above.
2. Mail the content of output.xls file as a body in email.

I think, Point2 is being achieved using below code but not getting how can i achieve Point1 in same program.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
Const FileToBeUsed = "c:\output.xls"
Dim objCDO1
Dim fso, f
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(FileToBeUsed, ForReading)
Set objCDO1 = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objCDO1.Textbody = f.ReadAll
f.Close
objCDO1.TO ="sunny@abc.com"
objCDO1.From = "dontreply@abc.com"
objCDO1.Subject = "Server Memory"
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration /sendusing") = 2 
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtpb.intra.abc.com"
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration /smtpserverport") = 25 
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Update     
objCDO1.Send
Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Note:My purpose here is to send email with properly formatted and aligned data.

**EDIT1:**

This is all i could do regarding points 1,2,3.
Don't know how to consolidate all this in a HTML email Body format..:(

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

Dim fso,f,objFSO,objFile,objRE, FileName
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

const strFileName1 = "D:\file1.txt"
const strFileName2 = "D:\file2.txt"

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName1, fsoForReading) +    objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName2, fsoForReading)
objobjFile.Close
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

---

```
Set objRE = New RegExp

With objRE
    .Pattern    = "[A-Z][0-9]"
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Global     = False
End With

Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
const strFileName1 = "D:\file1.txt"
const strFileName2 = "D:\file2.txt"

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName1, fsoForReading) +   objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName2, fsoForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strSearchString = objFile.ReadLine
    Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strSearchString)  
    If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
        For Each strMatch in colMatches   
            Wscript.Echo strSearchString 
        Next
    End If
Loop
    objFile.Close
```

---

```
Class memory1class
    Public operatingsystem, memory
End Class
Dim memory1dict: Set memory1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim memory2dict: Set memory2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim memory1: Set memory1 = new memory1class
With memory1
    .operatingsystem = "?"
    .memory = "?"

End With
memory1dict.Add "1", memory1

Dim memory1details: Set memory1details = memory1dict.Item("1")
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("operatingsystem:" & memory1details.first & " " &  memory1details.memory & " )
```

Comment: Are both input files guaranteed to have the same number of rows with the same labels in the first column?

Comment: @Ansgar..labels in the first column would be same always but number of rows could be same ,different and most probably in different order.
I have edited the question for maximum possible scenario.

Comment: @Ansgar...pls see EDIT1.

Comment: Copy/pasting non-working code snippets is not what I would consider putting in some effort of your own. Please try a little harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to directly give you code, because this is a good opportunity for you to learn more about the different options you have available for solving the problem yourself, but I can give you a rough outline of what I would do.

1. Open the two text files for reading.  Windows provides a "Scripting" library which contains the `FileSystemObject`.  You would declare an instance of it as below, and you can google for the specifics of how to use it to open a text file:

   ```
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   ```
2. Read each file in a line at a time. Parse each line to get the "name" part and the "number" part as distinct values. You can do this by combining the `InStr`, `InStrRev`, and `Mid` functions or you can use the more powerful RegExp library (VBScript's Regular Expression class).

   ```
   Set re = New RegExp
   ```
3. Store each "name" and "value" into a data structure for later use - I recomment an associative array such as VBScript's Dictionary class.  Using a separate one for each text file will allow you to cross-reference them later.

   ```
   Set dictStats1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   ```
4. To display the data formatted correctly in the email, I suggest using an HTML table.  In addition to the `TextBody`, the `CDO.Message` object has an `HTMLBody` property to allow you to give the email structured formatting instead of just raw text.  Extrapolating from the simple example on [w3school.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp), you can construct a function that will accept the two dictionaries and use them to construct the HTML table and return it as a string to be loaded into the email via the `HTMLBody` property.

I hope that helps! Let me know if you have any questions about the specifics.

Comment: @Steve..alright..let me try above myself first..in case i face any problem..i'll surely let you know..:)

Comment: @steve...pls see **EDIT1** which is all i could do :(