# Text output placement

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have two text files using which i want to get output.txt as follows:

**file1.txt:**

```
Windows                  1.36
Linux                    2.78
MacOS                    3.45
Ubuntu                   4.12
FreePhysicalMemory      30.12
TotalVisibleMemorySize  48.00
CPULoadPercentage         2
```

**file2.txt:**

```
MacOS                    6.39
Windows                  4.42
Linux                    5.76
Android                  3.46
FreePhysicalMemory      31.65
TotalVisibleMemorySize  48.00
CPULoadPercentage         4
```

**output.txt:**

```
OPERATINGSYSTEM       SERVER1    SERVER2
Windows                  1.36       4.42
Linux                    2.78       5.76
MacOS                    3.45       6.39
Ubuntu                   4.12       0.00
Android                  0.00       3.46
FreePhysicalMemory      30.12      31.65
TotalVisibleMemorySize  48.00      48.00
CPULoadPercentage         2          4
```

But the problem here is, using following code i am getting output.txt like below, in which **FreePhysicalMemory is being misplaced**..:

**code:**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set order[!i!]=%%a
   set info[%%a]=%%b
)

set total2=!order[%i%]!
set /A i-=1
set total1=!order[%i%]!
set /A i-=1

for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (file2.txt) do (
   if defined info[%%a] (
      set info[%%a]=!info[%%a]! %%b
   ) else (
      set /A i+=1
      set order[!i!]=%%a
      set info[%%a]=0.00 %%b
   )
)

set /A i+=1
set order[%i%]=%total1%
set /A i+=1
set order[%i%]=%total2%

(
echo OPERATINGSYSTEM       SERVER1    SERVER2
for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do (
   for /F %%a in ("!order[%%i]!") do (
      for /F "tokens=1,2" %%b in ("!info[%%a]!") do (
         set "os=%%a                      "
         set "s1=  %%b"
         if "%%c" equ "" (
            set "s2=     0.00"
         ) else (
            set "s2=     %%c"
         )
         echo !os:~0,22!  !s1:~-5!  !s2:~-9!
      )
   )
)
) > output.txt
```

**output.txt:**

```
OPERATINGSYSTEM       SERVER1    SERVER2
Windows                  1.36       4.42
Linux                    2.78       5.76
MacOS                    3.45       6.39
Ubuntu                   4.12       0.00
FreePhysicalMemory      30.12      31.65
Android                  0.00       3.46
TotalVisibleMemorySize  48.00      48.00
CPULoadPercentage         2          4
```

Comment: How "Misplaced?" What is the formula for the required sequence?

Comment: @Magoo..Hi..the formula as per the code is: 
**1.Read info from file1
2.Save totals
3.Read/merge info from file2
4.Return totals to end
5.Format and output information**

Comment: Certainly. What is the formula for determining the sequence of output? It appears arbitrary.

Comment: Magoo..but here what i see: when i remove 'CPULoadPercentage' row from file1.txt and file2.txt..then output.txt is coming in desired order as above.

Comment: As may be - but how is batch supposed to know what your 'desired order' is? You need to express that as a formula. Batch is very powerful, but sadly cannot yet read minds.

Comment: Agree Magoo.!.but not getting how i can set order in above code ?

Comment: The key in this problem is _How many total lines the data have?_ You must realize that 2 is NOT the same than 3! See my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, this happen because your [original request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532889/text-files-formatting-cum-consolidation) have *two lines of totals*, and your new request *have three*!

You must modify the program in order to include one line more of totals:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read info from file1
set i=0
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set order[!i!]=%%a
   set info[%%a]=%%b
)

rem Save totals
set total3=!order[%i%]!
set /A i-=1
set total2=!order[%i%]!
set /A i-=1
set total1=!order[%i%]!
set /A i-=1

rem Read/merge info from file2
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (file2.txt) do (
   if defined info[%%a] (
      set info[%%a]=!info[%%a]! %%b
   ) else (
      set /A i+=1
      set order[!i!]=%%a
      set info[%%a]=0.00 %%b
   )
)

rem Return totals to end
set /A i+=1
set order[%i%]=%total1%
set /A i+=1
set order[%i%]=%total2%
set /A i+=1
set order[%i%]=%total3%

rem Format and output information
(
echo OPERATING SYSTEM       SERVER1    SERVER2
for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do (
   for /F %%a in ("!order[%%i]!") do (
      for /F "tokens=1,2" %%b in ("!info[%%a]!") do (
         set "os=%%a                      "
         set "s1=  %%b"
         if "%%c" equ "" (
            set "s2=     0.00"
         ) else (
            set "s2=     %%c"
         )
         echo !os:~0,22!  !s1:~-5!  !s2:~-9!
      )
   )
)
) > output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks..Aacini..it solved my problem..'Save total' completely slipped my mind.:)

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET spaces=                                                         x
SET "line="
FOR /f "delims==" %%a IN ('set list 2^>nul') DO SET "%%a="
FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%a IN (file1.txt) DO SET list_%%a=%%b
FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%a IN (file2.txt) DO (
  IF defined list_%%a (CALL SET list_%%a=%%list_%%a%% %%b
   ) ELSE (SET list_%%a=0.00 %%b
  )
)
FOR /f %%v IN (list.seq) DO IF NOT defined list_%%v SET list_%%v=0.00 0.00
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3delims== " %%a IN ('set list 2^>nul') DO IF "%%c"=="" SET %%a=%%b 0.00
(
 CALL :show L 22 "OPERATING SYSTEM" L 9 "SERVER1" L 12 "SERVER2"
 FOR /f %%v IN (list.seq) DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=2,3,4delims==_ " %%a IN ('set list_%%v') DO SET "suppdec="&CALL :show L 22 %%a R 7 %%b R 9 %%c&SET "list_%%v="
  )
 FOR /f "tokens=2,3,4delims==_ " %%a IN ('set list_ 2^nul') DO SET "suppdec="&CALL :show L 22 %%a R 7 %%b R 9 %%c
)>output.txt
TYPE output.txt

GOTO :EOF

:show
IF "%~3"=="" GOTO output
IF %1==L (SET column=%~3%spaces%) ELSE (SET column=%spaces:~0,-1%%~3%suppdec%)
IF %1==L (CALL SET line=%%line%%%%column:~0,%2%%) ELSE (CALL SET line=%%line%%%%column:~-%2%%)
SHIFT&shift&SHIFT
ECHO "%~3"|FIND "." >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET "suppdec=  ") ELSE (SET "suppdec=")
GOTO show

:output
ECHO %line%
SET "line="
GOTO :eof
```

Where `list.seq` contains

```
Windows
Linux
Absent
MacOS
Ubuntu
Android
FreePhysicalMemory
TotalVisibleMemorySize
CPULoadPercentage
```

If an element is found in one file but not the other, `0.00` will appear for the missing data.

If a value does not contain a decimal, it will be shifted 2 spaces to align the unit column with the decimals.

Elements NOT appearing in the data files but that ARE mentioned in the `list.seq` file will appear with values 0.00

Elements appearing in the data files that are not mentioned in the `list.seq` file will appear in alphabetical order after those that DO appear in `list.seq`

Comment: @Magoo..tried but output is coming in following order:
**OPERATING SYSTEM,      
Android,                  
CPULoadPercentage,        
FreePhysicalMemory,      
Linux,                    
MacOS,                    
TotalVisibleMemorySize,  
Ubuntu,                   
Windows**

Comment: You will notice that the sequence is ALPHABETICAL. In all probability, the file `list.seq` does not contain the sequence of lines you require, or is not accessible - possibly you've misnamed it or you've saved it as `list.seq.txt`. There's nothing magic about the name - just change the filename in the `for /f %%v` lines to match - but make sure that the contents exactly match the text strings required. Perhaps copy `output.txt` to `list.seq` then edit `list.seq` to the sequence required and run again.

Comment: yeah..now I got it..thanks Magoo..its working with perfection..!!:)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an entirely different approach with the following features:

- The number of servers (files) is easily extensible. Simply add a new file to the list in the outer loop of the Load data section.
- The header for each server is derived from the file name by dropping the extension.
- The width of each server column is easily configurable
- The width of the OS label column is easily configurable
- Missing values are displayed as blank instead of a misleading 0
- OS labels are displayed in alphabetical order, followed by the summary rows.
- The number and order of summary rows at the end is easily configurable. Simply add or subtract values in the `lookup` variable.

I renamed FILE1.TXT, FILE2.TXT to SERVER1.TXT, SERVER2.TXT. I also copied SERVER1.TXT to SERVER3.TXT just so I could test value missing from previous column.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Clear any existing $ variables
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('"set $ 2>nul"') do set "%%A="

:: Load data
set "cnt=0"
set "blank=                                               "
set "width=8"
set "labelWidth=22"
set "lookup= FreePhysicalMemory:2 TotalVisibleMemorySize:3 CPULoadPercentage:4"
for %%F in (server1.txt server2.txt server3.txt) do (
  set "val=%blank%%%~nF"
  set "$0.OPERATINGSYSTEM=!$0.OPERATINGSYSTEM! !val:~-%width%!"
  for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (%%F) do (
    set "test=!lookup:* %%A:=!"
    if "!test!" equ "!lookup!" (set "prefix=$1.") else set "prefix=$!test:~0,1!."
    for %%P in (!prefix!) do (
      if not defined !prefix!%%A (
        for /l %%N in (1 1 !cnt!) do set "%%P%%A=!%%P%%A! !blank:~-%width%!"
      ) else if "!%%A!" neq "!cnt!" (
        set "%%P%%A=!%%P%%A! !blank:~-%width%!"
      )
      set "val=%blank%%%B"
      set "%%P%%A=!%%P%%A! !val:~-%width%!"
    )
    set /a "%%A=cnt+1"
  )
  set /a cnt+=1
)

:: Print results
for /f "tokens=2* delims=.=" %%A in ('set $') do (
  set "label=%%A%blank%"
  echo !label:~0,%labelWidth%!%%B
)
```

-- OUTPUT --

```
OPERATINGSYSTEM         SERVER1  SERVER2  SERVER3
Android                             3.46
Linux                      2.78     5.76     2.78
MacOS                      3.45     6.39     3.45
Ubuntu                     4.12              4.12
Windows                    1.36     4.42     1.36
FreePhysicalMemory        30.12    31.65    30.12
TotalVisibleMemorySize    48.00    48.00    48.00
CPULoadPercentage             2        4        2
```

---

***EDIT in response to OP comment***

Here is a modified version that uses NULL for missing values and writes the output to a text file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Clear any existing $ variables
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('"set $ 2>nul"') do set "%%A="

:: Load data
set "cnt=0"
set "blank=                                               "
set  "null=                                           NULL"
set "width=8"
set "labelWidth=22"
set "lineWidth=0"
set "lookup= FreePhysicalMemory:2 TotalVisibleMemorySize:3 CPULoadPercentage:4"
for %%F in (server1.txt server2.txt server3.txt) do (
  set "val=%blank%%%~nF"
  set "$0.OPERATINGSYSTEM=!$0.OPERATINGSYSTEM! !val:~-%width%!"
  for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (%%F) do (
    set "test=!lookup:* %%A:=!"
    if "!test!" equ "!lookup!" (set "prefix=$1.") else set "prefix=$!test:~0,1!."
    for %%P in (!prefix!) do (
      if not defined !prefix!%%A (
        for /l %%N in (1 1 !cnt!) do set "%%P%%A=!%%P%%A! !null:~-%width%!"
      ) else if "!%%A!" neq "!cnt!" (
        set "%%P%%A=!%%P%%A! !null:~-%width%!"
      )
      set "val=%blank%%%B"
      set "%%P%%A=!%%P%%A! !val:~-%width%!"
    )
    set /a "%%A=cnt+1"
  )
  set /a cnt+=1, lineWidth+=width+1
)

:: Print results
(for /f "tokens=2* delims=.=" %%A in ('set $') do (
  set "line=%%B !null:~-%width%!"
  set "label=%%A%blank%"
  echo !label:~0,%labelWidth%!!line:~0,%lineWidth%!
))>output.txt
```

Comment: Thats great Dbenham..worked like a charm..thanks..:)

Comment: @dbenham..I was trying to redirect the output to a file (so I added `>>output.txt` at extreme last) but that keeps appending the result into output.txt on every run (which is obvious), but I wanted to avoid that, I mean I want on every next run the existing data in output.txt should be cleared.
Please suggest..!

Comment: @Sunny - Use `>output.txt` after the last closing `)`.

Comment: @dbenham..I did but in that case , only `CPULoadPercentage` row is coming in output.txt. Moreover, I would appreciate if you can explain above script in some deatils, please. specially I was looking for where the feature no. 5 (Missing values as blank..) is being achieved in above script and If I want to put `0 or NULL` in place of all missing values, can i do that in above script ?

Comment: @Sunny - Oops, I forgot that an extra set of parentheses is needed around the entire display FOR loop. See my updated answer.

Comment: @dbenham.. I have tested the edited script on my servers where few issues have been reported. I have uploaded the complete test results  [Here..](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yl2rju9crl1v91x/ques_19739359.txt) Please could you review and suggest?

Comment: @dbenham..there seems to be very small point missing for this script to be completely perfect one. If number of files are four, then this script is generating few unexpected results. test input-Output is pasted [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yl2rju9crl1v91x/ques_19739359.txt) . Can you please have a look there ?

Comment: @dbenham.. to avoid much data-traffic congestion here, I've posted a separate question with all the issues encountered [here..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654212/joining-of-multiple-text-files) :-)